# How to load webpage with in the popup

Tags: popup

I have on-click popup on my wordpress website , which contains [woocommerce_order_tracking] 
i want to ajaxify track button , so that users can track their orders in the same popup without refreshing the page.

Comment: What do you mean you "want that link to load"? You want to display the linked webpage in your popup?

Comment: Yes , i want to ajaxify the pop-up so that i can load link without refreshing the page

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: No, thats what i want to know.

Comment: I'm confused... are you using jQuery or not?

Comment: No sir , I am not using anything , i am just creating wordpress website with plugins  & css . i know nothing about jquery and php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with using jQuery, Ajaxing in content and injecting it into your page is relatively straightforward. You can just use [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) depending on you you want to use the data. If you just want to inject it into your page, go for `.load()`. Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) on how to use that, but an example is below:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
// This will load the contents of "path/to/file.html in the div #result
$( "#result" ).load( "path/to/file.html" );
</script>
```

Comment: Thank  you ! i will try , but where should i put this script?

Comment: You can either include the script inline like I have displayed or created a separate JS file and link it up via `<script src="separate-file.js"></script>`. Make sure to include jQuery (and load it before any other script) too: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`